# Analyzing tricky one liners & having handy list of useful ones

Tags: linux, scripting

Have seen one liners like below & took a little time to analyse exact use & working of it – something like set the value to later one if it is not set.

```
export JDK_HOME=${JDK_HOME:-"/some/path/java-1.7"}
```

I have not seen tricky literals like ':-' when I search for something. Is there any handy list of such useful one liners documented or a specfic man page to refere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read `man bash`, and type `/Parameter Expansion` (exactly like this, with the leading slash). It will search for the relevant section from that man page; the possible expansion modifiers are explained there.

Comment: This is nice. It answered my question:

${parameter:-word}
              Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other fine answer with respect to consulting the documentation, I always turn to Bash's debug facility to see what's going on.

You can enable it and disable it by wrapping the commands of interest in a block like so:

```
$ set -x; command_to_watch; set +x
```

#### Example

```
$ set -x; export JDK_HOME=${JDK_HOME:-"/some/path/java-1.7"}; set +x
+ export JDK_HOME=/some/path/java-1.7
+ JDK_HOME=/some/path/java-1.7
+ set +x
```

Here you can see that the variable `$JDK_HOME` is being set to `/some/path/java-1.7`. However if we set it to something else:

```
$ export JDK_HOME=/a/path
$ echo $JDK_HOME
/a/path
```

And run this command again:

```
$ set -x; export JDK_HOME=${JDK_HOME:-"/some/path/java-1.7"}; set +x
+ export JDK_HOME=/a/path
+ JDK_HOME=/a/path
+ set +x
```

We can see that it didn't do anything, leading us to the fact that if the variable is already set, this command will leave it alone, otherwise it will set it with the value, `/some/path/java-1.7`.

Confirming our suspicion in [Bash's man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

```
${parameter:-word}
      Use Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word
      is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found The [Reference Cards in Appendix B](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html) of the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) very useful. The relevant table for your example would be [Table B-4: Parameter Substitution and Expansion](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html#AEN22568).